# Keep the format of the webpage while it is converted to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, printing

I am currently working in project where I have to print a web page which is like a form containing details of the students. When I try to print the web page using `window.print()` the format of the page changes in the PDF.

How do I keep the original format of the web page in the PDF also??
Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any other library that converts `html` to `pdf`

Answer (score 0):

**jsPDF is able to use plugins**. In order to enable it to print `HTML`, you have to include certain plugins and therefore have to do the following:

Go to [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and download the latest Version.
Include the following Scripts in your project:

- jspdf.js
- jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
- jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
- jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js

If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an `ID`, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of `jsPDF`. Therefore your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in a PopUp:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

For me this created a nice and tidy PDF that only included the line 'print this to pdf'.